# Render font size of maths in Rmarkdown slides when viewed in then Rstudio viewer

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown, mathjax

Writing some slides for lecture. I want to include a shiny app. I do not have admin rights on the lecture room computer, which means I can run my Rmd file and present the slides via the Rstudio viewer, but they will not display in a web browser. All the equations in the slides are in a smaller font when viewed in the Rstudio viewer, which kind of ruins everything. Does anyone know how to fix the math font size in the Rstudio viewer or the .Rmd file itslef, or another possible fix?

```
---
title: "Title"
output: ioslides_presentation
runtime: shiny
---

## Math Font Size
* Let $x=5$ be the same size as the text ...
```

[image]

Works fine when I don't want a shiny app...

```
---
title: "Title"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Math Font Size
* Let $x=5$ be the same size as the text ...
```

[image]

Comment: What are the versions of your rmarkdown, shiny, and RStudio? I think this issue has been reported before: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/273 and fixed in the latest version of RStudio (http://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/). You may also need to run `update.packages()` after upgrading RStudio.

Comment: @Yihui rmarkdown: 0.6.1, shiny: 0.11.1, RStudio 0.98.1103. (i.e. what is currently on CRAN and the main RStudio download page). Problem solved with preview edition of RStudio you linked to. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a version of RStudio beyond 0.98.1103.